# How to convert an XML file to pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, xml, dataframe, beautifulsoup, xmltodict

I cannot get XML to a python dataframe

Could you please help me to parse XML to python dataframe?
I can't seem to get it to work
This is how far I got to:

```py
import xmltodict 
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
 def get_xml():
    url="http://energywatch.natgrid.co.uk/EDP-PublicUI/PublicPI/InstantaneousFlowWebService.asmx"
    headers = {'content-type': 'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8'}
    body ="""<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
                <soap12:Body>
                <GetInstantaneousFlowData xmlns="http://www.NationalGrid.com/EDP/UI/" />
                </soap12:Body>
                </soap12:Envelope>"""

    response = requests.post(url,data=body,headers=headers)
    return response.content

response = get_xml()
soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'lxml')
table_columns = []
for item in soup.find_all(['EDPObjectName'.lower()]):
    table_columns.append(item.text)
table_columns=pd.DataFrame(table_columns)
table_rows=[]
for item in soup.find_all(['applicableat']):
    table_rows.append(item.text) 
df1=pd.DataFrame(table_rows).drop_duplicates() 
#df1=pd.to_datetime(df1)
table=[]
for item in soup.find_all(['flowrate']):
    table.append(item.text) 
df=pd.DataFrame(table)
 df_final=pd.DataFrame(df, columns=table_columns, index=df1)
```

This is the result I am looking for:

```
                    ALDBROUGH   AVONMOUTH   BACTON BBL  …
    2019-08-08T13:00:00 0       1.23    5.1         …
    2019-08-08T13:02:00 0       1.23    5.1         …
    2019-08-08T13:04:00 0       3.23    5.1         …
    2019-08-08T13:06:00 0       3.23    5.1         …
    2019-08-08T13:08:00 0       3.23    5.23            …
    2019-08-08T13:10:00 0       4.23    5.204           …
```

Comment: I'm happy to share a potential solution to this question, but are you sure that is the result you are looking for? The source data seems to suggest that ALDBROUGH, AVONMOUTH, BACTON etc. would be the rows, and the time and flowrate would be the columns.

Comment: Thank you very much. This problem is way beyond my basic knowledge.
Either combination works. 
The only reason for this format is given the data is updated every 12 minutes it might be easier to store and analyse but if you can help me to get flowrate as columns I would be grateful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

name_list = []

prev_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['time'])
response = BeautifulSoup(get_xml(), 'lxml')
for x in response.find_all('edpobjectbe'):
    list_small = list()

    name = str(x.find('edpobjectname').text).strip()
    name_list.append(name)

    data = x.find_all('edpenergydatabe')
    print(name)
    for y in data:

        applicableat = str(y.find('applicableat').text).strip()
        flowrate = str(y.find('flowrate').text).strip()

        list_small.append([applicableat, flowrate])
    df = pd.DataFrame(list_small, columns=['time', name])
    prev_df = pd.DataFrame.merge(prev_df, df, how='right', on='time')
print(prev_df)
```

Check if this works for you!!!

Answer (score 0):

This problem is very similar to other xml parsing problems in that you have a hierarchical data structure, and you need to flatten it. My proposed solution turns the timestamp, the place, and the flowrate into columns and makes every log entry a row. I've also followed a principle of parsimony, which is that I try parse the xml in a way so that my flattened data is already in the format that's easiest to convert into a dataframe. The variable 'data' has the structure of a dictionary with one key for each column. The values in the dictionary are lists of data, and each position in the list indicates which row the entry belongs to:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
def get_xml():
    url="http://energywatch.natgrid.co.uk/EDP-PublicUI/PublicPI/InstantaneousFlowWebService.asmx"
    headers = {'content-type': 'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8'}
    body ="""<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><soap12:Body><GetInstantaneousFlowData xmlns="http://www.NationalGrid.com/EDP/UI/" /></soap12:Body></soap12:Envelope>"""
    response = requests.post(url,data=body,headers=headers)
    return response.content

response = get_xml()
soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'lxml')

data = {'timestamp':[], 'place':[], 'flowrate':[]}

for group in soup.find_all('edpobjectbe'):
    place = group.find('edpobjectname').text
    for xml in group.find_all('edpenergydatabe'):
        data['place'].append(place)
        data['timestamp'].append(xml.find('applicableat').text)
        data['flowrate'].append(xml.find('flowrate').text)

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

Note that I am doing my find_all() on the parent element 'edpenergydatabe' so I can be sure the timestamp applies to all the entries associated with it. If you want a different arrangement of rows and columns, you can now use pandas functions like transpose() to do it. I hope this helps you get on the right track!